# Connection timeout when transferring file via FTP

Tags: unix, ftp, data-transfer

I am trying to upload my csv file to a Unix server using FTP in the Windows cmd window, and at the end of the process I get this message:

> 425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out

Why is this command not working?

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol is a little bit weird because it uses a separate control connection (for sending commands) and data connection (for transferring the files and directory listings). Basically there are [two modes: active and passive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699163/320437).

In your case the FTP client works in active mode (shows `200 PORT command successful`). So it opens a port tells it to the server and waits for the server to connect. Most probably there is something on the way which prevents this connection - for example NAT device (e.g. firewall) incapable of translating active FTP.

You can use an alternative FTP client to be able to switch the communication to the passive mode. From free software you can use for example [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) with CLI or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) with GUI. As Martin Přikryl remarked the `ftp.exe` client shipped with Windows does not support passive mode.